# Why won't my Test class pull the main class correctly?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Thank you for assisting me. I have written a Main class that I am able to compile and run. The problem I have is I can run the Test class using the display method.(not pulling correctly to new class) I have to create the Test class with 3 objects one with small value, large value, and retain value. I must use setRadius() method.  Any guidance you can provide would be very helpful.

```
public class Circle
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   //call constructor and method
      Circle myCircle = new Circle();
      myCircle.display();
   }
   //set fields
   double radius;
   double diameter;
   double area;
   //create constructor set radius & compute diameter and area.
   public Circle()
   {
       radius= 1;
       diameter = 2 * radius;
       area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
   }
   //set radius, diameter, and area
   public void setRadius()
   {
      radius= 1;
      diameter = radius * radius;
      area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
   }
  //return radius
   public double getRadius()
   {
      return radius;
   }
 //write display
   public void display()
   {
       System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
       System.out.println("The diameter is " + diameter);
       System.out.println("The area is " + area);
   }

}






public class TestCircle 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


       Circle circleA = new Circle();
       circleA.setRadius();
       System.out.println("Circle A: " + circleA.setRadius());

        Circle circleB = new Circle();
       circleB.setRadius();
       System.out.println("Circle B: " + circlB.setRadius());
   }


}
```

Comment: What does _not pulling correctly to new class_ mean?

Comment: I notice you have two `main()` methods. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I had to create a class Circle that names the 3 fields, and use setRadius getRadius to set radius to 1, and use setRadius to compute the diameter and area.   Now I have to create a TestCircle class that will do as I mentioned above.

Comment: I thought I had to pull the calculation from my first class to the new Test class

Comment: What does not pulling correctly to new class mean? I can get my Test Circle class to recognize Circle Class, but it pulls the display method.

Comment: *pulls the method* is not any kind of software terminology that anyone understands but you!

Comment: Ok, sorry new to this. I want to use the calculation I made for radius, diameter, and area in Circle class to be used in my Test class.  On TestCircle class I am trying to name circle A with a small value, circle B with a large value, circle C retain value. I may be coming at this wrong.

Comment: Create a class named Circle with fields named radius, diameter, and area.
Include a constructor that sets the radius to 1 and calculates the other two values.
Also include methods named setRadius() and getRadius(). The setRadius()
method not only sets the radius but also calculates the other two values.

Comment: Create a class named TestCircle whose main() method declares several
Circle objects. Using the setRadius() method, assign one Circle a small
radius value, and assign another a larger radius value. Do not assign a value to
the radius of the third circle; instead, retain the value assigned at construction.
Display all the values for all the Circle objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to call `display()` on your `Circle` instances. That would look something like,

```
public class TestCircle 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Circle circleA = new Circle();
    circleA.setRadius();
    // System.out.println("Circle A: " + circleA.setRadius());
    circleA.display();
    Circle circleB = new Circle();
    circleB.setRadius();
    // System.out.println("Circle B: " + circlB.setRadius());
    circleB.display();
  }
}
```

**Edit**

You create a `circleA` and a `circleB` but your `setRadius` method doesn't take a `radius` argument, also your math appears to be off.

```
public void setRadius(int radius)
{
  this.radius = radius;
  diameter = radius + radius; // <-- 2*radius (not radius*radius)
  area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
}
```

Then you can call `setRadius` with different radii in your `main()` like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Circle circleA = new Circle();
  circleA.setRadius(2);
  circleA.display();
  Circle circleB = new Circle();
  circleB.setRadius(4);
  circleB.display();
}
```

Comment: Thank You! When I try this I only get one output for circle A, and not sure how to name one circle a low value, and the 2nd circle a large value.

Comment: My void type on setRadius is not allowed system.out.println

Comment: @Soccer82 You can't pass a `void` to `println` nor you do you need to. You do need to modify `setRadius` so you can pass a radius.

Comment: Thank you! I can now use set radius; however still on displaying CircleA

Comment: @Soccer82 Read my answer again. You call `circleA.display()`. If You want to say the name as well, that would be `System.out.print("circleA: ");` then `circleA.display()`.

Comment: public class TestCircle 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Circle circleA = new Circle();
    circleA.setRadius(2);
    circleA.display();
    System.out.println("CircleA: " + circleA.display());
    Circle circleB = new Circle();
    circleB.setRadius(8);
    circleB.display();
    System.out.println("CircleB: " + circleB.display());
  
  }
}

Comment: produces void can't be used here in the Syste.out.println

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointer:

Use the constructor to set the initial value of the instance variables when creating the object. Use set radius to change the value after creation, if needed. diameter and area are variables that can be derived from the radius. I would suggest to write methods that returns these.

Also just do what do method name says it does. In setRadius for example just set the radius, nothing else.

```
public class Circle
{

   //set fields
   private double radius;

   //create constructor set radius & compute diameter and area.
   public Circle(double radius)
   {
       this.radius=radius;
   }
   //set radius
   public void setRadius(double radius)
   {
      this.radius = radius;
   }
   public double getDiameter()
   {
    return 2*radius;
   }

  //return radius
   public double getRadius()
   {
      return radius;
   }

   public double getArea()
   {
    return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
   }
 //write display
   public void display()
   {
       System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
       System.out.println("The diameter is " + getDiameter());
       System.out.println("The area is " + getArea());
   }

}


public class TestCircle 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

        Circle circleA = new Circle(1.0);
        circleA.display();
        Circle circleB = new Circle(2.0);
        circleB.display();

   }


}
```